# Call the correct overloaded mixin based on number of arguments

Tags: css, less

I am using [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) (pro) to generate some CSS from a LESS file. I have two mixins with the same name but a different number of arguments.

According to the [LESS docs](http://lesscss.org/#docs) the correct mixin should be automatically selected based on the number of arguments in the call. Here is the relevant section from the docs:

> We can also match on arity, here’s an example:
>
> ```
> .mixin (@a) {
>   color: @a;
> }
> .mixin (@a, @b) {
>   color: fade(@a, @b);
> }
> ```
>
> Now if we call .mixin with a single argument, we will get the output
>   of the first definition, but if we call it with two arguments, we will
>   get the second definition, namely @a faded to @b.

However this does not seem to be the case for me.

Below are two versions of a `.border-radius` mixin. The first takes a single argument, the second allows for a custom set of args to be sent. The class `#searchbox` calls the single argument mixin and the class `#search` calls the multi-argument mixin.

**LESS Mixins**

```
.border-radius (@radius: 5px) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}

.border-radius (@topleft: 5px, @topright: 5px, @bottomleft: 5px, @bottomright: 5px) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @topleft @topright @bottomright @bottomleft;
    -moz-border-radius: @topleft @topright @bottomright @bottomleft;
    border-radius: @topleft @topright @bottomright @bottomleft;
}

#searchbox {
    .border-radius(1px);
}

#search {
    .border-radius(2px, 3px, 4px, 5px);
}
```

The CSS that is generated does not respect the *Arity*  (the number of arguments). Instead it seems that calling with a single argument runs *both* the mixins while calling with multiple arguments runs the correct mixin alone, as the generated CSS below shows:

**Generated CSS**

```
#searchbox {
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 1px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 1px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#search {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px 3px 5px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px 3px 5px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px 3px 5px 4px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to omit the default values on the arguments or otherwise less will call the second mixin even with only one argument provided because it can use the defaults for the 3 "missing" arguments.

The following works as intended by you:

```
.border-radius (@topleft, @topright, @bottomleft, @bottomright) {
    /*...*/
}
```

However, now you will get an error when you try to call `.border-radius` with 2 or 3 arguments. You could provide default values for the third and forth value to have the mixin expect every number of arguments (1-4) and still not execute the second mixin for only one argument.

```
.border-radius (@topleft, @topright, @bottomleft:5px, @bottomright:5px) {
    /*...*/
}
```

So finally you could use (You can [safely omit the prefixes for borderadius](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) nowadays):

```
/* 1 arg */
.border-radius (@radius: 5px) {
    border-radius: @radius;
}
/* 2 args */
.border-radius (@tlbr,@trbl) {
    border-radius:@tlbr,@trbl;
}
/* 3 and 4 args */
.border-radius (@topleft, @topright, @bottomleft, @bottomright: 5px) {
    border-radius: @topleft @topright @bottomright @bottomleft;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I am kicking myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The two functions with 1 argument and 4 arguments, respectively, should suffice. I.e.:

```
.border-radius(@radius:0px) {
    -webkit-border-radius:@radius;
    -moz-border-radius:@radius;
    border-radius:@radius;
}
.border-radius(@topLeftRadius, @topRightRadius, @bottomLeftRadius:0px, @bottomRightRadius:0px) {
    -webkit-border-radius:@topLeftRadius @topRightRadius @bottomLeftRadius @bottomRightRadius;
    -moz-border-radius:@topLeftRadius @topRightRadius @bottomLeftRadius @bottomRightRadius;
    border-radius:@topLeftRadius @topRightRadius @bottomLeftRadius @bottomRightRadius;
}
```